# Apparent manufacturing defect in bathroom sink - overflow water leaks out firing hole under sink

Tags: plumbing, leak, sink, seal

Just finished adding a 1/2 bath and when I tested the sink with running water - no leaks. When I closed the popup and filled to overflow, water came out through a firing hole in the underside of the sink.

I assume if I simply plug that hole, I'll just wind up with an air cavity full of water (mold, etc.) so that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Instead, until I get the time to replace the sink, I was going to dry it out and inject a tube of silicone caulk into the sink overflow intake hole and also the overflow drain hole down where the popup sits.

OPINIONS?  Any reason this fix won't work for a while at least to buy me some time. It's my own house and not all sinks have overflows anyway.

RECOMMENDATIONS?  I am concerned that silicone won't cure in a sealed cavity. Is there something "better"?  I was thinking epoxy, but I doubt that will stick unless I scuff up the glazing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A new sink you want to return it in the same condition it came, with the defect intact/not blocked/sealed.  If not returning, silicon just in the leaking hole should be enough.  I am assuming the firing hole is in the overflow drain and any water should drain down where it should.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not going to bother to return it since I really don't have the time to pull it and replace it right now. The popup that came with the sink has the usual holes in the side to accept the overflow water and the overflow does drain "correctly" also - I tested without the popup installed. I'm guessing that there's a crack between the overflow path and the hollow part of the sink and the firing hole inadvertently became a backup overflow exit path.  The firing hole is 180 degrees opposite the overflow, so I'm guessing unrelated to overflow. Cheap HD sink (duh).